# if the class is not found append a int/Nan in bs4

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to figure out how to append an integer or a Nan when the class isn't found, but it seems not working, and instead is skipping the if/else statement.
any idea?

```py
rooms_bed = []                 
for a in soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class":"no-svg-bed-icon bed-icon seperator"}):
    for s in a.select('title'):
        if len(s) == 0:
            rooms_bed.append(0)
        else:
            rooms_bed.append(s.get_text())
           
number_bedrooms = []
for x in rooms_bed:
    if "bedrooms" in x:
        number_bedrooms.append(int(x.replace('bedrooms', '')))
```

Comment: Can you confirm the url of the page in question?

Comment: We can't reproduce without the html or link you're scraping from, but try adding `print(len(soup.select('span.no-svg-bed-icon.bed-icon.seperator title')))` 
 [or add **`print(len(a.select('title')))`** before *`for s in a.select('title')`*] to check if there *are* any `title` tags inside those `span` tags at all

Comment: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E1268&index=120&propertyTypes=&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords=
So, basically, there is one ad without the bedrooms because it is a land, so I'd like to be counted as a 0 in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am somehow fairly convinced this is yet another [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).
Therefore, here is one tested method of obtaining all data from that page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import re
import json

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E1268&index=120&propertyTypes=&includeSSTC=false&mustHave=&dontShow=&furnishTypes=&keywords='

soup = bs(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find(string=re.compile("^window.jsonModel")).split(' = ')[1]
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data)['properties'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
id  bedrooms    bathrooms   numberOfImages  numberOfFloorplans  numberOfVirtualTours    summary displayAddress  countryCode propertySubType premiumListing  featuredProperty    distance    transactionType commercial  development residential students    auction feesApply   feesApplyText   displaySize showOnMap   propertyUrl contactUrl  staticMapUrl    channel firstVisibleDate    keywords    keywordMatchType    saved   hidden  onlineViewingsAvailable hasBrandPlus    displayStatus   enquiredTimestamp   heading formattedBranchName addedOrReduced  propertyTypeFullDescription enhancedListing isRecent    formattedDistance   location.latitude   location.longitude  propertyImages.images   propertyImages.mainImageSrc propertyImages.mainMapImageSrc  listingUpdate.listingUpdateReason   listingUpdate.listingUpdateDate price.amount    price.frequency price.currencyCode  price.displayPrices customer.branchId   customer.brandPlusLogoURI   customer.contactTelephone   customer.branchDisplayName  customer.branchName customer.brandTradingName   customer.branchLandingPageUrl   customer.development    customer.showReducedProperties  customer.commercial customer.showOnMap  customer.enhancedListing    customer.developmentContent customer.buildToRent    customer.buildToRentBenefits    customer.brandPlusLogoUrl   productLabel.productLabelText   productLabel.spotlightLabel lozengeModel.matchingLozenges
0   128841404   3   1   19  1   0   Bridgfords Hazel Grove are over the moon to we...   Deneside Crescent, Hazel Grove, Stockport, Che...   GB  Semi-Detached   True    True    None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/128841404#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-07T17:22:14Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None    Featured Property   by Bridgfords, Hazel Grove  Reduced on 23/11/2022   3 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.382230   -2.110010   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-11-23T22:14:22Z    280000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£280,000', 'displayPriceQua...   93  /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_10_0001.jpeg 0161 524 4990   Bridgfords, Hazel Grove Hazel Grove Bridgfords  /estate-agents/agent/Bridgfords/Hazel-Grove-93...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Corner Plot False   []
1   114569264   3   2   14  1   1   A well presented DETACHED BUNGALOW enjoying a ...   Parsonage Gardens, Marple   GB  Bungalow    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/114569264#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2021-10-08T16:59:54Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   True    True        None        by Edward Mellor Ltd, Marple    Added on 08/07/2022 3 bedroom bungalow for sale False   False       53.388240   -2.060480   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-07-08T15:07:43Z    500000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£500,000', 'displayPriceQua...   28598   /company/clogo_rmchoice_12942_0000.png  0161 524 6040   Edward Mellor Ltd, Marple   Marple  Edward Mellor Ltd   /estate-agents/agent/Edward-Mellor-Ltd/Marple-...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...   Cul-De-Sac  False   [{'type': 'ONLINE_VIEWINGS', 'priority': 6}]
2   128949689   3   1   15  0   1   A rare opportunity to acquire this three bedro...   Delamere Close, Stockport, SK7  GB  Detached Bungalow   True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/128949689#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-10T12:42:26Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Ian Tonge Property Services Limited, Hazel...    Added on 10/11/2022 3 bedroom detached bungalow for sale    False   False       53.381600   -2.102170   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-10T12:48:02Z    500000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£500,000', 'displayPriceQua...   12271   /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_5724_0002.jpeg   0161 524 9316   Ian Tonge Property Services Limited, Hazel Grove    Hazel Grove Ian Tonge Property Services Limited /estate-agents/agent/Ian-Tonge-Property-Servic...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Premium Listing False   []
3   127513385   4   2   17  1   1   Julian Wadden are delighted to be selling this...   Boddens Hill Road, Heaton Mersey, Stockport, SK4    GB  Detached    False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127513385#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-09-28T15:41:42Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor   Added on 28/09/2022 4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.411211   -2.194055   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-09-28T15:47:04Z    500000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£500,000', 'displayPriceQua...   81832   /82k/81832/branch_rmchoice_logo_81832_0004.jpeg 0161 524 6124   Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor  Heaton Moor Julian Wadden   /estate-agents/agent/Julian-Wadden/Heaton-Moor...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/82k/8183...       False   []
4   128983526   6   2   15  1   1   A well presented large family home in a popula...   Shawbrook Road, Manchester, Greater Manchester...   GB  Semi-Detached   True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/128983526#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-11T11:10:01Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Bridgfords, Withington   Added on 11/11/2022 6 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.428500   -2.194710   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-11T11:15:05Z    500000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£500,000', 'displayPriceQua...   828 /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_10_0001.jpeg 0161 524 2534   Bridgfords, Withington  Withington  Bridgfords  /estate-agents/agent/Bridgfords/Withington-828...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Premium Listing False   []
5   125170034   4   2   31  3   1   A beautiful family home with this TASTEFULLY M...   Grasmere Crescent, High Lane, Stockport, SK6    GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/125170034#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-07-20T12:02:21Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Ian Tonge Property Services Limited, High ...    Reduced on 24/10/2022   4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.370442   -2.073502   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-10-24T10:12:21Z    499000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£499,000', 'displayPriceQua...   12272   /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_5724_0002.jpeg   0161 524 7425   Ian Tonge Property Services Limited, High Lane  High Lane   Ian Tonge Property Services Limited /estate-agents/agent/Ian-Tonge-Property-Servic...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Premium Listing False   []
6   127657994   4   3   13  1   0   Looking for a family home with bags of space a...   Harrisons Drive, Woodley, Stockport GB  Detached    False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127657994#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-10-03T13:21:25Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by On the Move Property Boutique, Hyde  Added on 03/10/2022 4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.428014   -2.086527   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-10-03T13:27:02Z    495000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£495,000', 'displayPriceQua...   123220  /124k/123220/branch_rmchoice_logo_123220_0005.png   0161 524 8664   On the Move Property Boutique, Hyde Hyde    On the Move Property Boutique   /estate-agents/agent/On-the-Move-Property-Bout...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/124k/123...       False   []
7   128921357   4   1   16  1   1   An impressive, fully refurbished 4 bedroom det...   Hermitage Gardens, Romiley, Stockport, Cheshir...   GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/128921357#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-09T16:10:16Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Lawler & Co, Marple  Added on 09/11/2022 4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.415631   -2.065066   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-09T16:16:02Z    495000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£495,000', 'displayPriceQua...   108866  /company/clogo_rmchoice_41135_0001.jpeg 0161 524 3922   Lawler & Co, Marple Marple  Lawler & Co /estate-agents/agent/Lawler-and-Co/Marple-1088...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...   High Specification  False   []
8   127524668   3   1   17  1   0   An immaculately presented and well maintained ...   Alvaston Avenue, Heaton Moor    GB  Detached    False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127524668#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-09-28T18:00:38Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by John Mellor Independent Estate Agents, Hea...    Reduced on 19/10/2022   3 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.415292   -2.186009   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-10-19T15:45:04Z    495000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£495,000', 'displayPriceQua...   4639    /5k/4639/branch_rmchoice_logo_4639_0000.jpeg    0161 524 4074   John Mellor Independent Estate Agents, Heaton ...   Heaton Moor John Mellor Independent Estate Agents   /estate-agents/agent/John-Mellor-Independent-E...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/5k/4639/...       False   []
9   127965329   3   1   19  1   0   A wonderful larger than average three double b...   Carlton Road, Heaton Mersey, Stockport, SK4 GB  Semi-Detached   True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127965329#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-10-12T16:16:41Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor   Reduced on 14/12/2022   3 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.415290   -2.194650   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-12-14T14:30:07Z    490000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£490,000', 'displayPriceQua...   81832   /82k/81832/branch_rmchoice_logo_81832_0004.jpeg 0161 524 6124   Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor  Heaton Moor Julian Wadden   /estate-agents/agent/Julian-Wadden/Heaton-Moor...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/82k/8183...   Premium Listing False   []
10  129519590   4   2   18  1   1   Occupying a delightful position at the head of...   Gloucester Avenue, Marple   GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/129519590#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-28T10:55:20Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   True    True        None        by Edward Mellor Ltd, Marple    Added on 28/11/2022 4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.396840   -2.067260   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-28T11:01:02Z    490000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£490,000', 'displayPriceQua...   28598   /company/clogo_rmchoice_12942_0000.png  0161 524 6040   Edward Mellor Ltd, Marple   Marple  Edward Mellor Ltd   /estate-agents/agent/Edward-Mellor-Ltd/Marple-...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...   Garage  False   [{'type': 'ONLINE_VIEWINGS', 'priority': 6}]
11  129229553   5   2   2   1   0   COMING TO THE MARKET SOON - We are inviting yo...   Kennerley Road, Davenport, Stockport, SK2   GB  Semi-Detached   False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/129229553#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-18T15:51:02Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Julian Wadden, Stockport Added on 18/11/2022 5 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.392527   -2.150971   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-18T15:57:01Z    485000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£485,000', 'displayPriceQua...   67998   /68k/67998/branch_rmchoice_logo_67998_0000.jpeg 0161 524 7110   Julian Wadden, Stockport    Stockport   Julian Wadden   /estate-agents/agent/Julian-Wadden/Stockport-6...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/68k/6799...       False   []
12  128381072   4   1   17  1   1   A stunning family home located a short walk fr...   Brooklands Road, Stockport, SK7 GB  Semi-Detached   True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/128381072#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-10-25T12:14:51Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Purplebricks, covering Stockport Reduced on 02/12/2022   4 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.372003   -2.121311   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-12-02T11:08:12Z    485000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£485,000', 'displayPriceQua...   75825   /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_87698_0003.png   020 3834 7974   Purplebricks, covering Stockport    covering Stockport  Purplebricks    /estate-agents/agent/Purplebricks/covering-Sto...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Premium Listing False   []
13  129576503   5   2   23  3   1   NOT BEEN ON THE MARKET FOR 35 YEARS! THIS VERS...   Bowfell Drive, Stockport, SK6   GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/129576503#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-29T16:32:21Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Ian Tonge Property Services Limited, High ...    Added on 29/11/2022 5 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.369764   -2.071565   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-29T16:38:04Z    485000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£485,000', 'displayPriceQua...   12272   /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_5724_0002.jpeg   0161 524 7425   Ian Tonge Property Services Limited, High Lane  High Lane   Ian Tonge Property Services Limited /estate-agents/agent/Ian-Tonge-Property-Servic...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Off-Street Parking  False   []
14  127281005   4   2   20  1   1   An impressive, THREE/FOUR BEDROOM, DETACHED FA...   Tennyson Close, Heaton Mersey, Stockport, SK4   GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127281005#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-09-21T16:06:17Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   True    True        None        by Philip James Kennedy, Heaton Moor    Reduced on 15/11/2022   4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.411088   -2.188637   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-11-15T12:58:24Z    485000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£485,000', 'displayPriceQua...   7571    /8k/7571/branch_rmchoice_logo_7571_0008.jpeg    0161 524 3546   Philip James Kennedy, Heaton Moor   Heaton Moor Philip James Kennedy    /estate-agents/agent/Philip-James-Kennedy/Heat...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/8k/7571/...   Premium Listing False   [{'type': 'ONLINE_VIEWINGS', 'priority': 6}]
15  127483358   3   2   37  1   0   Fabulous Victorian c1901 semi-detached of spac...   Davenport Road, Hazel Grove, Stockport SK7 4HA  GB  Semi-Detached   False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127483358#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-09-27T19:59:44Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Woodhall Properties, Hazel Grove Reduced on 31/10/2022   3 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.379861   -2.125069   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-10-31T13:53:57Z    479950  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£479,950', 'displayPriceQua...   922 /company/clogo_189_0000.jpg 0161 483 5100   Woodhall Properties, Hazel Grove    Hazel Grove Woodhall Properties /estate-agents/agent/Woodhall-Properties/Hazel...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...       False   []
16  124938890   5   2   26  1   1   ** OFFERS INVITED ** Rare opportunity to purch...   Bower Avenue, Heaton Norris, Stockport, SK4 GB  Semi-Detached   True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/124938890#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-07-13T17:59:48Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor   Reduced on 01/11/2022   5 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.415697   -2.175796   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-11-01T14:41:21Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   81832   /82k/81832/branch_rmchoice_logo_81832_0004.jpeg 0161 524 6124   Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor  Heaton Moor Julian Wadden   /estate-agents/agent/Julian-Wadden/Heaton-Moor...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/82k/8183...   Premium Listing False   []
17  122332742   4   5   16  1   1   Extended and very much improved detached with ...   Craig Road, Heaton Mersey, Stockport, SK4   GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/122332742#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-04-12T22:56:29Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Purplebricks, covering Stockport Added on 12/04/2022 4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.408552   -2.195049   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-04-12T23:02:01Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   75825   /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_87698_0003.png   020 3834 7974   Purplebricks, covering Stockport    covering Stockport  Purplebricks    /estate-agents/agent/Purplebricks/covering-Sto...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   Premium Listing False   []
18  127330814   4   2   12  1   2   An impressive FOUR DOUBLE BEDROOM detached wit...   Kinross Avenue, Woodsmoor, Stockport, Cheshire...   GB  Detached    False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127330814#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-09-22T18:11:23Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   True    True        None        by Lawler & Co, Hazel Grove Reduced on 14/10/2022   4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.380745   -2.144872   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-10-14T11:01:12Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   120697  /company/clogo_rmchoice_41135_0001.jpeg 0161 524 8681   Lawler & Co, Hazel Grove    Hazel Grove Lawler & Co /estate-agents/agent/Lawler-and-Co/Hazel-Grove...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...       False   [{'type': 'ONLINE_VIEWINGS', 'priority': 6}]
19  127937918   2   1   28  1   1   Set in a prime central village location this h...   Longhurst Lane, Marple Bridge, SK6  GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127937918#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-10-12T09:29:39Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   True    True        None        by Julian Wadden, Marple    Added on 12/10/2022 2 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.399128   -2.052152   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-10-12T09:35:03Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   123928  /124k/123928/branch_rmchoice_logo_123928_0002....   0161 524 3443   Julian Wadden, Marple   Marple  Julian Wadden   /estate-agents/agent/Julian-Wadden/Marple-1239...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/124k/123...   Village location    False   [{'type': 'ONLINE_VIEWINGS', 'priority': 6}]
20  129435305   4   1   14  1   0   Bridgfords are over the moon to welcome to the...   Shepley Close, Hazel Grove, Stockport, SK7  GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/129435305#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-24T14:33:00Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Bridgfords, Hazel Grove  Added on 24/11/2022 4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.370440   -2.122900   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-11-24T14:38:03Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   93  /brand/brand_rmchoice_logo_10_0001.jpeg 0161 524 4990   Bridgfords, Hazel Grove Hazel Grove Bridgfords  /estate-agents/agent/Bridgfords/Hazel-Grove-93...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/brand/br...   No Chain    False   []
21  129803789   3   1   16  1   0   *****NO CHAIN*****A superb opportunity to purc...   Marsham Road, SK7   GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/129803789#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-12-07T15:13:51Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Leighton Snow, Bramhall  Added on 07/12/2022 3 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.373750   -2.136140   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-12-07T15:19:05Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   195578  /company/clogo_rmchoice_59957_0000.jpeg 0161 524 6749   Leighton Snow, Bramhall Bramhall    Leighton Snow   /estate-agents/agent/Leighton-Snow/Bramhall-19...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...   Potential to extend (STPP)  False   []
22  128790602   4   1   25  4   1   A superb opportunity to acquire this unqiue fa...   Dialstone Lane, Stockport, SK2  GB  Detached    True    False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/128790602#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-11-06T11:15:03Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Strike, Nationwide   Reduced on 06/12/2022   4 bedroom detached house for sale   False   False       53.393875   -2.131655   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-12-06T17:00:07Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   29376   /company/clogo_rmchoice_7671_0010.png   020 3835 4350   Strike, Nationwide  Nationwide  Strike  /estate-agents/agent/Strike/Nationwide-29376.html   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...   Substantial Plot    False   []
23  127181315   3   2   11  1   0   A brand-new development of 4 modern semi-detac...   Broadstone Road, Heaton Chapel, Stockport, SK4  GB  Semi-Detached   True    False   None    buy False   True    True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/127181315#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-09-17T13:18:30Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   False   True        None        by Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor   Added on 17/09/2022 3 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.429003   -2.174603   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   new 2022-09-17T13:24:01Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   81832   /82k/81832/branch_rmchoice_logo_81832_0004.jpeg 0161 524 6124   Julian Wadden, Heaton Moor  Heaton Moor Julian Wadden   /estate-agents/agent/Julian-Wadden/Heaton-Moor...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/82k/8183...   Premium Listing False   [{'type': 'NEW_HOME', 'priority': 3}]
24  126025148   4   1   12  1   1   A rare opportunity to acquire an Edwardian Sty...   Mile End Lane, Stockport, Cheshire, SK2 GB  Semi-Detached   False   False   None    buy False   False   True    False   False   False   None        True    /properties/126025148#/?channel=RES_BUY /property-for-sale/contactBranch.html?property...   None    BUY 2022-08-12T17:05:36Z    []  no_keyword  False   False   True    True        None        by Lawler & Co, Hazel Grove Reduced on 08/11/2022   4 bedroom semi-detached house for sale  False   False       53.395507   -2.134795   [{'srcUrl': 'https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/crop/10:...   price_reduced   2022-11-08T16:31:25Z    475000  not specified   GBP [{'displayPrice': '£475,000', 'displayPriceQua...   120697  /company/clogo_rmchoice_41135_0001.jpeg 0161 524 8681   Lawler & Co, Hazel Grove    Hazel Grove Lawler & Co /estate-agents/agent/Lawler-and-Co/Hazel-Grove...   False   True    False   True    False   None    False   []  https://media.rightmove.co.uk:443/dir/company/...       False   [{'type': 'ONLINE_VIEWINGS', 'priority': 6}]
```

You can slice & dice that json object further, to get only the info you're after. Relevant pandas documentation can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Comment: Isn't taking all in consideration since in the page there's 25 ads and in your list there's 24, really nice script, do you prefer to work with JSOn?

Comment: @FedericoGottardi: the index starts from 0, and goes up to 24, making the total count 25 ... And it's not a matter of me preferring to work with JSON, as much as me preferring sometimes to help others.